# Why wont Webrowser1.Url go to my string?

Tags: vb.net, web

My goal is to save the webpage that the user is currently on,but I get an error.
Here is my code:

```
Dim C As String = "C:\"
Dim website As String = WebBrowser1.Url 'errors here!
Dim LocalFilePath As String = C + website
Dim objWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
objWebClient.DownloadFile(website, LocalFilePath)
```

the error is it wont let me jam that URL into my string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebBrowser1.Url` returns an object of type [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), not a string. You're trying to assign the Uri to a string, so either convert it to a string, or change `website` to be of type `Uri`.

```
Dim website As String = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()
```

or

```
Dim website As Uri = WebBrowser1.Url
```